# Socket gives me error when i try to connect -python

Tags: python, sockets

im trying to learn about sockets and i cant manage to connect to the ip,port.
this is the script i got:

## stian's socket test tool

```
import socket

print "send request to website to check if sockets work right"
ip = raw_input("website ip: ")
port = raw_input("website port: ")
socket.connect(ip, port)
tosend = "this is a test"
currVal = 0
while currVal < 1:
    socket.send(tosend)
    print "1 sockets sent..."
    currrVal += 1
print "Done sending sockets. This hopefully worked"
```

is anything wrong with the python code?
does this only work with ipv4 or ipv6? or does it work with both?

**ERROR IM GETTING:**

```
C:\Users\Swipper\Documents\Python\sockets>sock.py
send request to website to check if sockets work right
website ip: 127.0.0.1
website port:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Swipper\Documents\Python\sockets\sock.py", line 8, in <modu
le>
    socket.connect(ip, port)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

hope someone know the answer.

**PS: I Use python 2.7!**

-stian

Comment: Your question is kind of vague. Please include the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `.connect()` on the module instead of an object. You will have to instantiate a socket object first, which is normally achieved via `socket.socket()`. You can then call `.connect()` on the object that is returned.

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((ip, int(port))
```

Comment: Is the port required or optional?

Comment: Required, of course. How else would Python know which port to connect to? In some very rare cases (non-TCP/UDP protocols) you may probably ignore this, but that's most likely not the case for you.

Answer (score 2):

You must first create a socket object:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((ip, int(port))
```

instead of:

```
socket.connect(ip, port)
```

Then use `s.send`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the argument to the connect call be a tuple?

```
socket.connect((ip, port))
```

And check the return value of the `send` call.

Also, you won't get to know if the other end closed connection unless you receive something. Receiving is the only sure way to know if the connection has been closed.

**Edit:** And like the others say, you have to create a socket object.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt Nope, didn't see the edit until after I posted my answer. But I still feel I bring up a couple of good points.